# Is a table with multiple columns going to achieve any increase of speed during inserts if 4 columns of text length 1 are changed to enum field?

Tags: mysql, performance

I have a table with 16 columns containing a variation of integer, one varchar(50), and text fields.

Four of the columns are one char in length for storing Y or N. One column is 3 chars in length that could be changed to a ENUM.

Would there be any significant performance increase during inserts, if the four 1 char fields and one 3 char field were changed to enums?

Thanks in advance for the advice.

Comment: I really don't think it will make any difference to the performance. But this is just from my experience of using mysql. I'm not a MySQL DBA.

Comment: There is going to be a cost since enum will validate input but not enough to worry about. Personally I think enums are more of a curiosity than useful.

Comment: `CHAR(1)` and `ENUM` have essentially the same performance.

Comment: Thank you all.  I think I will stick with a CHAR(1) for ease and future portability to another DB.